# Capture everything until specific chars using named groups

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will capture everything until a dot or a comma, and I'm using named groups to do that.

Here's what I have:

```
String pattern = "(?<Words>(?=,|.))";
String text = "Part one, part two. Part three";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group("Words"));
}
```

I want to capture "Part one", since it is everything before the first comma. Then capture everything until the first dot, which is "part two". The regex in my code doesn't seem the be working, it outputs nothing, I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to adapt your code to work, here you go:

```
String pattern = "(?<Words>[^ ,.][^,.]*(?=(,|\\.)))";
String text = "Part one, part two. Part three";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group("Words"));
}
```

`[^ ,.]` says starts with a non-space, comma or period character
`[^,.]*` says any amount of non-comma or period characters
`(?=(,|\\.))` is the positive lookahead for a comma or period, which must be escaped, since `.` in a regex is a special character which means "anything except for a new-line character"

Yours doesn't work because you have nothing before your positive look-ahead.

Answer (score 0):

How about use method `String.split` instead here.

```
    String pattern = "[,|\\.]";
    String text = "Part one, part two. Part three";
    String[] strsBySplit = text.split(pattern);
    for (String s : strsBySplit) {
        System.out.println(s.trim());
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to escape or use `|` in a character class, ie `"[,.]"` is all you need.

Comment: Also, this gets "Part three".